# Bug: User account option controls displayed for moderators in others' profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed

Viewing any user's profile brings up the "prefs" and "flair" sections and, under the "accounts" tab, the "Copy Webmasters profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts" and "Clear all Stack Exchange account associations" options are displayed.

So far as I am aware, these controls are not appropriate for use over the course of moderation activities and the potential for accidentally performing a destructive action on someone's account associations or preferences is probably best avoided.

Comment: I just checked myself and I can confirm that I see the buttons.  I don't know what happens when you click them, they could not work but I don't want to risk it.

Comment: @RandomBen - You're welcome to try the "clear account association" button on my profile's "account" tab, I can always re-associate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disassociating and re-associating are staying around for a bit longer, as they're useful to moderators attempting to help user's recover associations and gain missed rep bonuses.  They are in the process of being phased out in favor of more auto-magic system behavior.

You're right about the Copy Profile button though.  Historically, it didn't matter much that mods could do it (as developers can) but with the increase in the size of the network that function really should be restricted just to the user in question.  The next build will rectify this.